# What will be the output of the below java code in case of partial failure during API calls?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, rest

I have a list of total 115 inputs, which is divided into a packets size of 20 inputs each using the below code, which means `xoneIndexListOfList` has 6 elements with size `[ [20], [20], [20], [20], [20], [15] ]` respectively.

```
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
final Collection<List<XoneIndexRequest>> xoneIndexListOfList = xoneIndexRequestList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / xoneIndicesPacketSize))
              .values();
```

In second step, I am iterating over this list and passing each packet as an input to some REST ENDPOINT, using the below code.

```
return xoneIndexListOfList.stream()
       .map(e -> {
            return getResponseBody(creditIndicesApiClient.creditIndicesSearch7(e));
       }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

From the above code, we could see that 6 calls will go to the above API(i.e.one for each packet), so here my question what will happen in case there is some partial failure?

**Scenario :**
Suppose packet 1 and 2 passed and packet 3 failed ( i.e. API not able to return data for 3rd packets)

**Question : **

1. In the above scenario will it proceed to 4 and 5 packets? If yes, then suppose packets 4 and 5 also passed, so in total packet 1,2,4,5 passed but 3 failed, so what will be the return output from the above code?
2. If no, they will be just returned the output for packets 1 and 2 because it was already passed and the request failed for packet 3?
3. or will it marked each packet to be failed if any one of it would fail at any time, of this packet list processing?

**EDIT - Adding the full method**

```
@Override
public List<XoneIndexResponse> creditIndicesSearch7(List<XoneIndexRequest> xoneIndexRequestList) {

    try {

        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        final Collection<List<XoneIndexRequest>> xoneIndexListOfList = xoneIndexRequestList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / xoneIndicesPacketSize))
            .values();

        return xoneIndexListOfList.stream()
            .map(e -> {
               return getResponseBody(creditIndicesApiClient.creditIndicesSearch7(e));
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error while retrieving data from x-one! for Index", e);
        return emptyList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an unhandled exception occurs, the processing of the stream stops immediately.

So you won't get a list unless you handle the exception.

We can test it with the following code:

```
Stream.of(6, 0, 7)
        .map(integer -> 5/integer + integer)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.lambda$main$8(DemoApplication.java:244)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:245)
```

It depends on what we are trying to do, but we can fix it by:

```
Stream.of(6, 0, 7)
        .map(integer -> {
            try{
                return  Optional.of(5/integer + integer);
            }catch (ArithmeticException e){
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        })
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
6
7
```

---

**Edit:**

When the whole thing is wrapped in a `try` scope, the exception that was thrown from the stream will propagate and be caught in the `catch` scope.

So in your case, an error will be printed to log and `emptyList()` will be called.

Comment: above whole code is written in try-catch block,, now what will be the behaviour?

Comment: @MOnkey I edited to answer your question :)